# Automatically export everything from ES5 file to be used in ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have pretty straightforward ES6 code (`init.js`):

```
import App from '../vendor/app';

window.init = function() {
  let app = new App();
  app.hello(); // prints "hello" to console
}
```

`app` module (`app.js`) is ES5 one and I don't want to modify this file:

```
function App() {
}

App.prototype.hello = function() {
  console.log('hello from vendor module');
}
```

The code above won't work, because I need to add

```
export default App;
```

to the end of `app.js`. But I want to keep vendor files clean and without any modification as much as it possible. The tricky part is that `app.js` is depending on other ES5 modules, for example:

```
App.prototype.hello2 = function() {
  dialog.show('hello from vendor app module, but using another vendor "dialog" module');
}
```

`dialog` variable is defined in ES5 `dialog.js`.

It works well when you add script-tags to your html page. I also want to avoid that. Ideally, I want to modify init.js only. Use some sort of import, so it will attach all of the vendor modules automatically to my `init.js`.

Comment: So, you want to import something without exporting it first?

Comment: Yep. The reason for this: legacy and already existing vendor library I don't want to touch.

Comment: Is this for Node, or with a bundling tool like Browserify/Webpack?

Comment: it's bundling with browserify